# How to print values of a list in Go

Tags: list, go

I've got some values in a list in Go. I just need to be able to print them but every time I try it tells me test.FirstName undefined (type *list.Element has no field or method FirstName).

So how to I appropriately access the members of the list? Its the last couple of lines that are giving me trouble.

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
    "os"
    "container/list"
)

type Student struct {
    FirstName string
    LastName  string
    testScore int
    homeworkScore int
}

func main() {

    fmt.Println("What is the name of your file?\n") 
    var filename string 
    fmt.Scan(&filename)

    file, err := os.Open(filename)
    if err != nil {
     log.Fatal(err)
    }
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)
    //var numLineCount int = 0
    var gradeCount = 0

    var student Student
    var studentList list.List
    var studentCount int = 1

    for scanner.Scan() {
        line := scanner.Text()

        fields := strings.Fields(line)
        student.FirstName = fields[0]

        student.LastName = fields[1]

        scanner.Scan()
        line2 := scanner.Text()
        sum := 0
        gradeCount = 0
        for _, field := range strings.Fields(line2) {
            n, err := strconv.Atoi(field)
            if err != nil {
                        log.Fatal(err)
                    }
            gradeCount++
            sum += n
        }
        student.testScore = sum/gradeCount
        gradeCount = 0

        scanner.Scan()
        line3 := scanner.Text()
        sum2 := 0
        for _, field := range strings.Fields(line3) {
            n, err := strconv.Atoi(field)
            if err != nil {
                        log.Fatal(err)
                    }
            gradeCount++
            sum2 += n
        }
        student.homeworkScore = sum2/gradeCount
        studentList.PushBack(studentCount)
        studentCount++

        fmt.Println("First:", student.FirstName, "Last:", student.LastName, "Test Avg:", student.testScore, "Homework Avg:", student.homeworkScore)
        }
        test:=studentList.Front()
        fmt.Println(test.FirstName)

    }
```

update: so I figured out i can't use test.FirstName in the println part, just Println(test) works and prints everything. but I still need to be able to access each element of the list. How can I do so?

Comment: Do you *need* to be using `containers/list`? Did someone ask you to? Is it purely a curiosity thing? Because it's probably a pretty bad idea. Just use a slice.

Comment: @hobbs unfortunately its for an assignment where we must use lists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you don't have the object type handy. you can use assertion to get the actual object type, something like the following:

```
  test:=studentList.Front()
  if actualStudent, ok := test.Value.(Student); ok {
      fmt.Println(actualStudent.FirstName)
  }
```

If it doesn't help, please leave a comment with the issue you face and I will be more than happy to assist you.

Comment: It gave me  invalid type assertion: test.(Student) (non-interface type *list.Element on left)

Comment: use `test.Value.(Student)` instead, plz chk updated answer

Comment: Whoops I guess I accidentally deleted that part before I ran it (its been a long day). That seems to have fixed it. Thank you so very much

Answer (score 1):

A quick read through the code. You are pushing `studentCount` into the list which is an int variable according to your declaration. I think what you are trying to achieve is pushing in the `student` struct instead. Typo?

P.S. If this is not a piece of homework or something with specific requirements, just use a slice instead. Always use a slice.

Comment: unfortunately it is for an assignment that specifically says to use lists. Thanks for the help! I'll see what I can make of it

Comment: now ive got test:=studentList.Front()
  fmt.Println(test) and its printing &{0xc0000644b0 0xc000064390 0xc000064390 {Chris Millsap 77 71}}